# Conjugation of $R_x(\theta)$ with $CNOT$

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

Section 2.5 (4.3) of the Qiskit textbook, [see here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/proving-universality.html#4.3-Expanding-the-Gate-Set-), discusses the conjugation of $R_x(\theta)$ by $CNOT$. The following expression is given:

$$CX_{j,k}(R_x(\theta)\otimes 1) CX_{j,k}=\color{brown}{CX_{j,k}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}(X\otimes1)}CX_{j,k}=e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}CX_{j,k}(X\otimes 1)CX_{j,k}}}=e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}X\otimes X}$$

I am confused by the part highlighted in yellow. What exponentiation rules allow this? Could someone show me the intermediate steps or the relevant identities/rules to take us from the LHS to RHS of the highlighted part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application of the following identity

$$
Be^AB^{-1} = e^{BAB^{-1}}\tag1
$$

where $A$ is any $n\times n$ real or complex matrix and $B$ is any invertible $n\times n$ real or complex matrix.

**Proof of $(1)$.** First, recall that the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) of $A$ is defined as

$$
e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}A^k.
$$

Next, note that for any integer $k$

$$
(BAB^{-1})^k = BAB^{-1}BAB^{-1}\dots BAB^{-1} = BAA\dots AB^{-1} = BA^kB^{-1}\tag2.
$$

Finally, calculate

$$
e^{BAB^{-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(BAB^{-1})^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}BA^kB^{-1} = B \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}A^k\right) B^{-1} = Be^AB^{-1}
$$

where we used $(2)$ in the second step. $\square$

Comment: Thanks so much, Adam! It now makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)